# How to filter records received before last month

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to filter all records received before last month, but still not getting it right,

i have tried:

```
month[tablename]![recieved_date] < month(dateAdd("m"; -1;Date())
```

Comment: Need parentheses: `Month([recieved_date]) < month(DateAdd("m"; -1; Date()))`. `Recieved` is incorrect spelling. Is that actually how field name is spelled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be:

```
[tablename]![recieved_date] < DateSerial(Year(Date()), Month(Date()) - 1, 1)
```